# How to achieve this given css glass effect with color that is leaking?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, blur, card

[image]

I want to recreate this glassy card, but I don't know how to achieve this I can get the glassy effect but can't achieve this blur color effect and I used backdrop filter property of CSS but it's not working

Comment: Look at `background` property with `radial-gradient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `background: radial-gradient()` + `backdrop-filter: blur()`:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.card > * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card:before,
.card:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.card:before {
  background:  radial-gradient(circle at 50% 20%, rgba(255, 0, 0, .6), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0));
}

.card:after {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .4;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  border: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam, ullam?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need backdrop-filter ))

Comment: @Kosh If there are no elements under the card, yes.